# Group all the similar id as one in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create an dyamic form with Jquery, there will be the multiple select box and textbox, how can I group the data into one based on the user name. For example, there will be the multiple select box = lim, total = 20, how can I group this 2 into array as 1.

[image]

When click the save button the final data will be like below

```
array(
  'lim' => 40,
  'tan' => 10,
);
```

Code here: https://jsfiddle.net/7gbvfjdc/

Comment: Your code should not be behind a link. Create a runnable snippet in your question using the appropriate button in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this ?

You save button event listener should have following code

```
$('.savebtn').on('click', function() {
  var mapObj = {};
  $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item) {
    var selectVal = $(this).find('select').val();

    if (mapObj[selectVal]) {
      mapObj[selectVal] += Number($(this).find('#amt1_' + index).val());
    } else {
      mapObj[selectVal] = Number($(this).find('#amt1_' + index).val());
    }

  });

  console.log(mapObj);
});
```

```js
var i = 0;
$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();

});

function addRow() {

  var tr = '<tr class="cb" id="row_' + i + '"><td>';
  tr += '<select class="form-control select2" id="name1_' + i + ' first" name="name[]">';
  tr += '<option>tan</option><option>lim</option></select></td>';
  tr += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_' + i + '" class="form-control"></td>';

  tr += '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>';
  tr += '</td></tr>';
  i++;
  $('tbody').append(tr);

}

$('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$('.savebtn').on('click', function() {
  var mapObj = {};
  $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item) {
    var selectVal = $(this).find('select').val();

    if (mapObj[selectVal]) {
      mapObj[selectVal] += Number($(this).find('#amt1_' + index).val());
    } else {
      mapObj[selectVal] = Number($(this).find('#amt1_' + index).val());
    }

  });

  console.log(mapObj);
});
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered listable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>amount</th>

      <th style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-center">

  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary savebtn">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` on the `body tr`s to extract the data and sum it in the wanted object format. Like this:

```js
const result = $('tbody tr').get().reduce((prev, ne) => {
  const $this = $(ne);
  const type = $this.find('select').val();
  prev[type] += parseInt($this.find('input').val())
  return prev;
}, {
  lim: 0,
  tan: 0
});
```

```js
var i = 0;
$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
  /*             
    $('.select2').select2({
        theme: 'bootstrap4',
        ajax: {
            url: '{{ route("getMember") }}',
            dataType: 'json',
        },
    }); */
});

function addRow() {
  i++;
  var tr = '<tr id="row_' + i + '"><td>';
  tr += '<select class="form-control select2" id="name1_' + i + ' first" name="name[]">';
  tr += '<option>tan</option><option>lim</option></select></td>';
  tr += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_' + i + '" class="form-control"></td>';
  /*  tr  += '<td><select class="form-control select2" id="name2_'+i+'" name="name2[]">';
   tr  += '<option>tan</option><option>lim</option></select></td>';    
   tr  += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt2_'+i+'" class="form-control"></td>'; */
  tr += '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>';
  tr += '</td></tr>';
  $('tbody').append(tr);
}

$('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$('button').on('click', () => {
  const result = $('tbody tr').get().reduce((prev, ne) => {
    const $this = $(ne);
    const type = $this.find('select').val();
    prev[type] += parseInt($this.find('input').val())
    return prev;
  }, {
    lim: 0,
    tan: 0
  });

  console.log(result)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>amount</th>
      <th>Second name</th>
      <th>Second amount</th>
      <th style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</a></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="text-center">

  </tbody>
</table>
<button>
  save
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/moshfeu/20kczto7/14/